# Effective Lagrangians

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, renormalization, effective-field-theory

I get the impression from reading, e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0002180), that the term "effective Lagrangian" refers to a Lagrangian derived from a Taylor series expansion of an arbitrary function of known invariants.  In the case of the vacuum electromagnetic field, the invariants are $F =(E^2 -B^2)$ and $G =(E \cdot B)$, and an effective Lagrangian is derived from $\sum_{mn} k_{mn}F^mG^n $. The constants $k_{mn}$ are adjusted to produce field equations that fit observed values due to, for example, vacuum polarization.  If I understand correctly, then, an "effective Lagrangian" is a Lagrangian with an infinite number of "free" parameters that are adjusted to fit observations; and typically all $k_{mn}$ where $m+n >4$ are assumed to be zero for all practical purposes.

In that case, it seems that the usual Lagrangian given for the electromagnetic field is, itself, an effective Lagrangian in which all $k_{mn}$ where $m+n >$ are set to zero.

I also get the impression that the term "effective Lagrangian" is used a bit apologetically, because tossing in too many adjustable parameters seems like cheating: the more adjustable parameters, the less elegant the science seems.

I'd like to know if my understanding is correct.  If it is, there will be more questions to follow--

Comment: I suppose the nicely written introduction to the paper on the first page answers most of your questions. And no, it's not a Taylor series. As mentioned in the intro, one writes all possible terms consistent with symmetries. These are usually higher dimension operators, so they come with non-renormalizable, negative dimension coupling constants. Sure, you introduce new free parameters, but then you determine/put bounds on them through experiment. This procedure parameterizes the high energy theory we're currently unaware of.